# Unable to create a WebSocket connection with Go and JS

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, connection, gorilla

I'm trying to create a simple Web Socket connection with server written in Go with Gorilla and client-side using JavaScript, but I don't understand why I get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' failed: Unexpected response code: 404

I launched my main.go with: go run main.go and my live server with: live-server.

**Client-Side:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage WebSocket</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
            console.log("Tentativo di connessione");

            socket.onopen = () => {
                console.log("Connessione riuscita")
                socket.send("Ciao dal Client!")
            }

            socket.onclose = (event) => {
                console.log("Connessione chiusa: ", event)
            }

            socket.onerror = (error) => {
                console.log("Errore socket: ", error)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***Server-Side:***

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin:     func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}

func reader(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        log.Println(string(p))

        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connessione Client riuscita!")

    reader(ws)
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", wsEndpoint)
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go WebSockets")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: The function `setupRoutes` is not called by the program.  Fix the problem by calling `setupRoutes` before the call to `http.ListendAndServe`.

Comment: omgf, what a shame. I add a little question about my project. Could it be a good idea using Gorilla? Or is it better writing native web socket or using another library like Socket.IO? We think that we handle max 100 users connection, we have to create rooms where each rooms contain a game.

Comment: If by "native" you mean the `golang.org/x/net/websocket` package, then you should use Gorilla as recommended by [documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket) for `golang.org/x/net/websocket` package.  Socket.IO adds a layer of functionality over WebSockets and other transports.  Use Socket.IO only if you find that extra functionality to be useful.